# Difference System Acceptance Test and User Acceptance Test

Tags: testing, acceptance-testing, manual-testing, user-acceptance-testing

I've read the terms System Acceptance Test and User Acceptance Test in a document.

But I can't really figure out what's the difference between these two.

Can anybody explain the difference?

Answer (score 4):

There is no official terminology in testing. Usually, the context in which they are used in the document should help find out the exact meaning the author have in mind.

From my experience though, I would say:

- *system* acceptance testing is more about platforms, OS, browser type etc. It is about using the SUT in a close-to-reality set of environments that ressemble the one the SUT is going to be used in. The actual test effort might be to have a set of end2end tests that you will run in those difference environments.
- *user* acceptance testing focus more on the end-user experience. What you will check is that the user gets what he wants from the SUT, feature by feature. Here you will take a single platform/env and run many different smaller tests to check the feature one by one. You can do this by following test plans or with a more exploratory approach

Comment: There are [glossaries of testing terms](http://www.aptest.com/glossary.html#positivetesting); yet it's still unclear to me what exactly the differences are between (as defined on that page) acceptance testing and end-to-end testing.

Answer (score 1):

User acceptance testing is done by client or customer.It will take place in client place.They will check whether the application meeting the requirements or not.

system acceptance testing is the testing done on a particular application in different environments such as different OS, Browsers, browser versions etc.It is usually done in developer location only.

Answer (score 1):

UAT- after completion of testing cycle, application goes to user acceptance testing it means client or user will test that application then that application will be live.

SAT- are special control systems developed to control the functionality of subsystem before sending the acceptance to the provider or system to check if the equipment to be accepted fulfills its specifications.

Answer (score 1):

System Acceptance Testing (SAT):- **

It is end-to-end testing wherein testing environment is similar to the production environment.We can also called it End to End testing.
Here, we navigate through all the features of the software and test if the end business / and feature works. We just test the end feature and don’t check for data flow or do functional testing and all.

**
**

- User Acceptance Testing (UAT)

**:-Acceptance testing is done by end users. Here, they use the s/w for the business for a particular period of time and check whether the s/w can handle all kinds of real-time business scenarios / situations.

Comment: You may want to edit the *'s.

Answer (score 0):

> System Testing: Finding the defects, when the system is tested as a whole, this also called as end to end testing. In this testing, tester needs to test the application from log-in to log-out.
>
> UAT: User acceptance testing is to get the acceptance from the client. UAT is generally done at client's environment. Before UAT pre UAT should be done.

Lifted from http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/19127